# Astro build failing in netlify

Tags: yaml, config, blogs, astrojs, decap-cms

So I set up the astro as recommended by their official tutorial at https://docs.astro.build/en/tutorial/0-introduction/. I went further and did as they suggested for content collections https://docs.astro.build/en/tutorials/add-content-collections/.
Then I set up the decap cms as suggested by the tutorial here https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/cms/decap-cms/.

Everything worked fine and the setup was flawless. Everything was deploying correctly upon git commit.
Then I logged in mysite/admin in the decap cms. I made a demo blog post and then tried to publish it. But it is always having build error in netlify.

This is the error that I was encountering.

```
4:40:00 PM: **Failed during stage "building site": Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2**
4:40:00 PM: **[InvalidContentEntryFrontmatterError] posts → 2024-02-04-my-first-blog-post-through-cms.md frontmatter does not match collection schema.**
4:40:00 PM: pubDate: Required
4:40:00 PM: author: Required
4:40:00 PM: image: Required
4:40:00 PM: tags: Required
4:40:00 PM:   Hint:
4:40:00 PM:     See https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/content-collections/ for more information on content schemas.
4:40:00 PM:   Error reference:
4:40:00 PM:     https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/errors/invalid-content-entry-frontmatter-error/
4:40:00 PM:   Stack trace:
4:40:00 PM:     at getEntryData (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/astro/dist/content/utils.js:86:26)
4:40:00 PM:     at async Object.transform (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/astro/dist/content/vite-plugin-content-imports.js:74:67)
4:40:00 PM:     at async ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (file:///opt/build/repo/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:17810:36)
```

I searched some documentation and came to know that the config.yml file should have the collections appropriately ordered with my config.ts schema.

**This is my config.ts (location of file: /src/content/config.ts)**

```js
// Import utilities from `astro:content`
import { z, defineCollection } from "astro:content";

// Define a `type` and `schema` for each collection
const postsCollection = defineCollection({
    type: 'content',
    schema: z.object({
      title: z.string(),
      pubDate: z.date(),
      description: z.string(),
      author: z.string(),
      image: z.object({
        url: z.string(),
        alt: z.string().optional()
      }),
      tags: z.array(z.string())
    })
});

// Export a single `collections` object to register your collection(s)
export const collections = {
  posts: postsCollection,
};
```

**This is config.yml(location of file: /public/admin/config.yml)**

```
backend:
  name: git-gateway
  branch: main 

publish_mode: editorial_workflow

media_folder: "src/assets"
public_folder: "assets"

collections:
  - name: "postsCollection"
    label: ""
    folder: "/src/content/posts"
    create: true
    slug: "{{slug}}"
    fields:
      - {label: "Layout", name: "layout", widget: "hidden", default: "blog"}
      - {label: "Title", name: "title", widget: "string"}
      - {label: "Publish Date", name: "pubDate", widget: "datetime"}
      - {label: "Description", name: "description", widget: "string"}
      - {label: "Author", name: "author", widget: "string"}
      - {label: "Featured Image", name: "image", widget: "image", fields: [
          {label: "URL", name: "url", widget: "string"},
          {label: "Alt Text", name: "alt", widget: "string"}
        ]}
      - {label: "Tags", name: "tags", widget: "list", field: {label: "Tag", name: "tag", widget: "string"}}
      - {label: "Body", name: "body", widget: "markdown"}
```

**How should I go on to solve this issue?
**
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the `2024-02-04-my-first-blog-post-through-cms.md` file that decapcms created? to reproduce it locally (on your computer), you should git pull the update decapcms made and then on your computer run `npm run build`. probably you get the same error now and can fix it more quickly...

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved for me by just matching the schema exactly in config.ts to the collections in config.yml

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).